# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView on absolute positioned component not working on ios

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard

I have a simple screen with a video player and a chat box overlay at the bottom (chatbox position absolute).

Here's a simple example of what I am doing.

Code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView>
    <Video style={{ height: Dimensions.get('window').height }} />
  </ScrollView>
  <ChatBox />
</View>
```

I use `Scrollview` to avoid video shrinking when the keyboard appears on android.

ChatBox:

```
<View style={{
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: 0,
}}>
  <FlatList 
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Message item={item} />}
  />
  <TextInput />
</View>
```

When I wrap `ChatBox` with `KeyboardAvoidingView` it doesn't work on ios, android is fine.
`ChatBox TextInput` remains under keyboard on ios.

I tried making `KeyboardAvoidingView` to absolutely positioned then adding `behavior='padding'`, it didn't work also.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: 0,
}} behavior='padding' >
  <FlatList 
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Message item={item} />}
  />
  <TextInput />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Sorry for my bad English and Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about the issue in your code but you should consider moving to KeyboardAwareScrollView Library which is way better that the one provided by react native

Comment: Somehow after all those years it has still not been fixed and no answer has been given here.